# Linking PDF file to a polygon shape with relative paths?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, pdf, hyperlink, file-path

I´m looking for a solution to connect a specific PDF file to each polygon in my shape and to create an action to open the PDF. Relative paths are required.

I am aware many people already asked this kind of question, but they´ve been 
asked and answered years ago.

I´m using QGIS Madeira 3.4.11 (long term release) and Windows 10 (64 bit).

My file structure is like this:

Gemeinde.qgs

-Daten

--Oekokonto

---Datenblaetter

----10.pdf

With absolute paths I did it like this:

action type: open

action: [%Datenblatt%]

[image: action]

The absolute filepath is in the column "Datenblatt" in my attribute table.

Example: X:/Projekte/QGIS/Daten/Oekokonto/Datenblaetter/10.pdf

What do I have to change to have relative instead of absolute paths?

Edit:

Attribute table:

[image: attribute table]

[image: action_2]

Comment: Are the PDFs stored in the same directory as your shapefiles? Is there a column which just has the name of the pdf (e.g. "10.pdf")?

Comment: The Shapefile is saved in "Daten". Yes a column with the number exists. (e.g. 10.pdf should be linked to 10 in the mentioned column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a Python method you could try. Change your *Typ* to *Python* and then use some code like the following:

```
import subprocess
path = QgsProject.instance().readPath("./") + "/Daten/Oekokonto/Datenblaetter/"
file = path + "[%Maßnahm_Nr%]" + ".pdf"
subprocess.Popen([file],shell=True)
```

[image: Action to load pdf]

Comment: It works. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Barbara. - Most welcome, glad it helped :). The method by nielsgerrits can also be useful when you want to update the paths in your attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use @project_path (this is where the QGIS project file lives) to replace the deprecated part with the project folder.

For example, if you have

```
D:\tmp\New folder (38)\data\test.txt
```

then use

```
[%replace(path,'D:\tmp\New folder (38)',@project_path)%]
```

Comment: I used `[%replace(path,'X:/Projekte/',@project_path)%]` as action. But when I click with it on a polygon nothing happens.

Comment: If your projectfile is in X:/Projekte/QGIS, you need to use [%replace(path,'X:/Projekte/QGIS',@project_path)%]. If you hit the sum sign you can see the preview in the lower left corner and check if the replace string is producing what you need.

Comment: You´re right. I changed it, but there is still nothing happening. Not even an error message.

Comment: May need to change the backslashes with slashes .
[%replace(replace(path,'X:/Projekte/QGIS',@project_path),'\\','/')%] (Unix vs Windows.)

Comment: Do I need to replace them in the attribute table as well and if that is the case replace them with \ or \\ ?

Comment: Just check how the path looks in your explorer and reproduce that.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it (Screenshots above), but there is still nothing happening.

Comment: Replace the entire block [%replace(path,'X:/Projekte/QGIS',@project_path)%] from your screenshot by [%replace(replace(path,'X:/Projekte/QGIS',@project_path),'\\','/')%]

Comment: Maybe come over to https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis :)

Comment: I replaced it, but sadly still nothing. I´m sorry, but I don´t have enough reputation to chat. :(

Comment: LOL. I uploaded an example to wetransfer:
https://we.tl/t-LkhKOZwcie
1. Does that work for you?
2. Are you on windows?

Comment: Nothing happens when I use your action on your example either. Yes, windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: @nielsgerrits - Does this action command actually load the PDF file? It doesn't seem to include the name of the column in which to load the relevant file.

Comment: @Joseph in my example is an empty test.txt under data. The path attribute has the filename (D:\tmp\New folder (38)\data\test.txt) and replaces D:\tmp\New folder (38) with '@project_path'... not sure what can go wrong.